# What is the reason for Malformed Packet Error using tcpdump (DDoS attack with LOIC)?

Tags: network, wireshark, python

[image: capture]

[image: capture error]

I used:  tcpdump -s 0  -i eth0 -v -w capture.pcap

The PCAP file: https://ufile.io/0502b

I executed the LOIC tool PythonLOIC :

python2 -W ignore loic.py

https://code.google.com/archive/p/pythonloic/downloads?page=2

Comment: Adding the text of the error to the body of your question might help, especially for people using mobile devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for malformed packets could be a broken network connection, out of range wifi signal or even a DDoS attack for example.

Another thing, to avoid problems with .pcap or .cap files, why not save it to a .txt file? Here is a sample command to save data onto a text file:

```
tcpdump -X -vv -i eth0 > tcplog.txt
```

Also note when using -s option(from tcpdump manpage):

> Note that taking larger snapshots both increases the amount of time it takes to process packets and, effectively, decreases the amount of packet buffering.  This may cause packets to be lost.